# Do skew symmetric matrices ever naturally represent linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am used to thinking of matrices in terms of linear transformations, but it occurred to me that skew-symmetric matrices are a potential counterexample.

I can think of at least two examples in which skew symmetric matrices crop up:

- As a representation space for $\wedge^2(V)$ for some vector space $V$. One of presumably very many examples of this occurs on pp. 226-227 of Bhargava's [Higher Composition Laws I](http://modular.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/was/travel/2011/msri/bhargava/bhargava-higher_composition_laws_I_a_new_view_of_Gauss_composition_and_quadratic_generalizations.pdf); one interesting feature of this construction is that the determinant of the matrix you get is interesting, being the square of a naturally occuring polynomial equation of the matrix entries (the Pfaffian).
- As the [Lie algebra of the orthogonal group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Lie_algebra).

In neither case does one naturally regard $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrices as acting by linear transformations on an $n$-dimensional vector space.
Is there a case where one does?

Comment: In fluid mechanics, the anti-symmetric part of the strain tensor does play a role. And it arises as a transformation of the form $$\mathbf{x}\mapsto \omega \times \mathbf{x},$$ where $\times$ is the vector product of $3$-dimensional space. Does it count as an example?

Comment: The  matrices in the Lie algebra of $O(n)$ act naturally on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  When $n=3$ one obtains the situation described by Giuseppe Negro.

Comment: I think that the essential question is what you mean by 'naturally'.  For a general vector space $V$ over a field, there is nothing natural about skew-symmetric matrices, as this condition is not preserved by an arbitrary choice of basis (which is how one gets a 'natural' correspondence between linear transformations and matrices in the first place).  However, for a vector space $V$ endowed with a non-degenerate symmetric inner product that can be written as a sum of squares, the choice of an orthonormal basis for the inner product produces the natural correspondences you mention.

Comment: Thanks to all: @Liviu: Guiseppe's example is very nice, but I understand that the cross product exists only in 1, 3, and 7 dimensions? Do you just mean in an infinitesimal sense, or would one ever "naturally" write down the action of a matrix in the Lie algebra of $O(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$? If the latter, I would be very grateful if you would explain further.

Comment: @Robert: Thank you very much. I guess I mean (roughly) an action that has some nice geometric interpretation, or which is studied in some other context. If I understood correctly, your last sentence is not answering my question in the affirmative?

Comment: @  Frank The infinitesimal  action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ of a matrix  in the Lie algebra of  $O(n)$  is the usual action   of a $n\times n$ matrix on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The  Lie algebra of $O(3)$  is $3$-dimensional and can be canonically  identified with $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the Pauli matrices. Under this identification, the Lie algebra action becomes the cross product.    Also, I think that Robert Bryant makes a very good point.